# How can I get top 3 items sold in particular three days in MDX queries?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

This is my MDX query. This will the items that is sold on particular three days. This query returns all items sold, but I wish to get only top 3 items on that particular dates.

How do I can get this? Here's my MDX query:

```
select
{
    [Measures].[Quantity],
    [Measures].[Net Sales]
}
on columns,
NON EMPTY
ORDER
(
    (
        [Products].[Item Description].children    
    ),
    [Measures].[Quantity], DESC
)
    * [Calendar].[Date].[Date]
on rows
from
(
select 
{
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-23T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-21T00:00:00]
}
ON columns

FROM [SalesReport])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TopCount` function as below:

```
select
{
    [Measures].[Quantity],
    [Measures].[Net Sales]
}
on columns,
NON EMPTY
TopCount([Products].[Item Description].children * [Calendar].[Date].[Date], 
        3,
        [Measures].[Quantity])      
on rows
from
(
select 
{
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-23T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-21T00:00:00]
}
ON columns

FROM [SalesReport])
```

To get the top 3 records for each date, you can user the `GENERATE` function :

```
select
{
    [Measures].[Quantity],
    [Measures].[Net Sales]
}
on columns,
NON EMPTY
GENERATE([Calendar].[Date].[Date],  
        TopCount([Products].[Item Description].children, 
                3,
                [Measures].[Quantity])  
        )   
on rows
from
(
select 
{
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-23T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00],
    [Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-21T00:00:00]
}
ON columns

FROM [SalesReport])
```

Comment: Sourav, Great. This shows top 3 items on all these days. Can we be able to get top 3 items sold on 23rd, 24th and 25th March?

Say for example,
March 23
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
March 24
Item 1
.... like this!

Comment: Will come up with an edit. In future, please either bunch together all your questions or ask a new question. Don't ask another question in the same thread.

Comment: Sorry! That's my mistake. Can I add new question or is this enough now?

Comment: That's fine. In future please follow the practice.

Comment: Sure! Sorry again! :-(

Comment: Have edited by question and added an answer. Check it please.

Comment: I'm not on my PC now, please give me sometime. I'll check and will let you know!